# How enable eventcart extension in WordPress CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, extension, modules

after an update of wp civicrm plugin from 5.16.4 to 5.30.1. (WordPress is also up to date).
When I subscribe to an event this fatal error appear :
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'CRM_Event_Cart_BAO_Conference' not found in civicrm/CRM/Event/BAO/Event.php:1133

File : "civicrm/CRM/Event/BAO/Event.php:1133"

`$sessions = CRM_Event_Cart_BAO_Conference::get_participant_sessions($participantId);`

Maybe the problem is due to a wrong setting ?
I kept my old civicrm.settings.php as it is after update.

It seems eventcart extension is not installed or activated.
I mean this extension : wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/eventcart/

Do you know how install/enable it?

Thank you for you help.
Nicolas

Comment: Just a thought - there are other approaches available to paying for multiple events, especially if those events are part of a Series for example - just in case there is a better solution now than event cart

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing event cart should be enabled but hidden, and currently still relies on the setting under Administer - CiviEvent - Component Settings to switch on and off features. You can verify if the extension is enabled by running this SQL: `select is_active from civicrm_extension where name='eventcart';`

If it's not, in civi go to Support - Developer - api explorer v3 and choose Entity=Extension, and Action=Enable, and for the key parameter put `eventcart`. Then click execute at the bottom. The upgrade should have done that though. There should be a record that it did that in ConfigAndLog.

Comment: There is only one extension is this table (it's my custom payment extension).
Nothing else.
Same result in api explorer v3.

Comment: Maybe can help : I can see all files of eventcart in the directory.
So, I think it's installed but not enabled.

Other info, it seems there are 2 different directories for extensions : 

    in plugin core : wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/
    and in upload dir : wp-content/uploads/civicrm/

In 1st one, there is eventcart extension and others.
In the second one, I have my custom payment extension.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The reason was very simple.
In my settings file located in WordPress upload files, I set :
`$civicrm_root = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';`

I change it into absolute real path :
`$civicrm_root = /var/www/html/mysite/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';`

After that, I was able to enable the extension "eventcart" with api explorer v3.
It seems the "../" is not allowed by civi in last version.

Nicolas